# Can proliferate be applied to loyalty counters?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am curious, can proliferate be applied to planes-walkers with loyalty counters on them?

proliferate text states:

> You choose any number of permanents and/or players with counters on them, then give each another counter of a kind already there.

And planeswalkers are both players AND permanents, So I see no reason that it shouldn't work. Are there rules against it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can proliferate loyalty counters on planeswalkers because they are permanents.

Planeswalkers are not players however, the only time they sort-of act like players is *"If noncombat damage would be dealt to a player by a source controlled by an opponent, that opponent may have that source deal that damage to a planeswalker the first player controls instead."* And really that is just a rule so that cards like [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d) will be effective against them without needing errata.

> **110.4.** There are five permanent types: artifact, creature, enchantment, land, and **planeswalker**.

Comment: So... In theory, could I use ral zarek (http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=ral+zarek) with some inexorable tides (http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397762)  to possibly gain infinite turns via quick, plentiful, cheap spells?

Comment: @tuskiomi You can, though there are significantly easier (and more reliable) ways to get infinite turns

Comment: ...go on... I want to hear

Comment: @tuskiomi That isn't really what comments are for, but if you join us in [chat] we could answer that question for you.

Comment: Quickly just for anyone looking in from the outside, the big one everyone knows about for infinite turn combos would be the Time vault - Voltaic Key combo, often simplified to Volt(Vault)-Key.